# Why is Trino SQL truncating microseconds and nanoseconds to milliseconds?

Tags: sql, trino, sql-timestamp, nanotime, starburst

Why is Trino truncating six digits of nanoseconds, leaving only milliseconds?

The [Trino documentation](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html) gives the following example:

```sql
SELECT from_iso8601_timestamp_nanos('2020-05-11T11:15:05.123456789+01:00');
-- 2020-05-11 11:15:05.123456789 +01:00
```

However, when I run this same statement on Trino, I get the following:

```sql
SELECT from_iso8601_timestamp_nanos('2020-05-11T11:15:05.123456789+01:00');
-- 2020-05-11 06:15:05.123 -04:00
```

I'm not concerned with the timezone adjustment; I'm concerned with the loss of precision of the timestamp.

Why am I losing this precision?

Is there another way to retain this precision?

Comment: you can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77165222/is-there-a-function-to-extract-the-time-part-of-a-datetime-variable-in-trino-sql/77936896#77936896).