# Is there a function to extract the time part of a datetime variable in Trino SQL?

Tags: sql, datetime, timestamp, trino, starburst

Is there a function to extract the time part of a datetime variable in Trino SQL, including nanoseconds?
--AND/OR--
Is there a corresponding comparison operator that allows comparison to just the time part of a datetime variable in Trino SQL (including nanoseconds)?

I know I can use HOUR(), MINUTE(), SECOND() to extract these elements, but I can't find a "one-shot" function to extract the time from a timestamp.

For example, if the time is '2020-05-11 11:15:05.123456789 +01:00', I would like to know if there is a function that returns `'11:15:05.123456789'` (i.e., no date part). I can cast the datetime to time (e.g., `CAST(my_date_time_variable as time)`, but this doesn't give fractional seconds. E.g., `CAST('2020-05-11 11:15:05.123456789 +01:00' as time)` yields `'11:15:05'`, dropping the fractional seconds.

```sql
magical_trino_sql_function('2020-05-11 11:15:05.123456789 +01:00')
-- '11:15:05.123456789'
```

or

```sql
magical_trino_sql_function('2020-05-11 11:15:05.123456789 +01:00')
-- 11:15:05.123456789
```

Why do I want to do this?

I would like to use a WHERE statement like the following.

```sql
WHERE magical_trino_sql_function(date_time_variable) BETWEEN 09:30:00.000000000 and 16:00:00.000000000
```

This is the clunky code that comes close to working now:

```sql
WHERE my_date_time_variable BETWEEN date_add('minute', 30, date_add('hour', 9, my_date_variable)) AND
date_add('hour', 16, my_date_variable)
```

where `my_date_time_variable` looks like `2020-05-11 11:15:05.123456789 +01:00` and `my_date_variable` looks like `2020-05-11`.

A problem I encounter is that the fractional seconds past milliseconds seem to be truncated and the resulting time is rounded, so something like `2020-05-11 09:29:59.999876543 +01:00` gets rounded to `2020-05-11 09:30:00.000 +01:00`, but I wouldn't want to include that in the above WHERE statement.

When I compare dates, I use something like

```sql
WHERE date_variable BETWEEN date'2023-07-01' AND date'2023-07-31'
```

Is there something to compare just the time part of a datetime variable with fractional seconds? For example:

```sql
WHERE my_date_time_variable BETWEEN time'09:30:00.000' AND time'16:00:00.000'
```

The nanoseconds matter, but I'm having problems with this as well; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77159453/why-is-trino-sql-truncating-microseconds-and-nanoseconds-to-milliseconds).

I have searched the [Trino documentation](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html) and the typical search engines and have come up empty. I also reviewed the questions that come up when asking the question to make sure my question isn't a duplicate. Some of the questions helped me improve my question, but I'm still having problems.

Comment: I took a quick look at the [Trino Documentation](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html) and found the `date_format()` function which seems like it might satisfy your requirement?

Comment: So I guess something like `SELECT date_format(TIMESTAMP '2023-09-25 11:22:15.456', '%H:%i:%S.%f')` - I don't have this DBMS installed to test this, so won't post as an answer unless you let me know it works.

Comment: @3N1GM4 I did `SELECT date_format(TIMESTAMP '2023-01-10' 09:30:00.123456789-05:00', '%H:%i:%S.%f')` and Trino returned `09:30:00.123000` so the microseconds and nanoseconds are still truncated.  The section in the Trino Documentation under "MySQL date functions" for %f states "Fraction of second (6 digits for printing: `000000`... `999000`; 1-9 digits for parsing: `0`...`999999999`, timestamp is truncated to milliseconds." Does this mean that nanoseconds are retained (e.g., for comparisons) buy not displayed?

Comment: @Misha please do not forget to [accept and upvote](https://kormteamcity.avp.ru/buildConfiguration/KormB_LicenseManager_ProductionSmokeTests_ProductionSafeData?mode=builds) answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should circumvent the Trino limitation on nanoseconds by treating the value as a string rather than a timestamp. The second step involves separately extracting the time without nanoseconds and the nanosecond component itself. Finally, calculate the total number of nanoseconds so you can use it in the WHERE clause with BETWEEN:

```sql
with temp_table as 
(SELECT  cast(split(split( '2023-01-10 09:30:00.123456789', ' ')[2],'.')[1] as time) as houres_minutes_seconds, 
cast(split(split( '2023-01-10 09:30:00.123456789', ' ')[2],'.')[2] as int) as nanoseconds)
  SELECT 
  (EXTRACT(hour FROM houres_minutes_seconds) * 3600000000000) + 
  (EXTRACT(minute FROM houres_minutes_seconds) * 60000000000) + 
  (EXTRACT(second FROM houres_minutes_seconds) * 1000000000) + nanoseconds AS total_nanoseconds
from temp_table
```